# Proxy.config.json invalidSymbol [1,1]

Tags: json, angular-cli

I am trying to add proxy to change the origin to the server
like

from `http://localhost:4200/api/deaprtment/get/2`

to `http://localhost:7201/api/department/get/2`

note that `localhost:4200` is what my angular app run in

and `localhost:7201` is what my asp.net server run in

my proxy-config.json is

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:7201",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

it's in src/proxy-config.json

my angular.json is

```
.
.
.
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "test2:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "test2:build:development",
              "proxyConfig": "src/proxy-config.json"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
.
.
.
```

and when run `ng serve`
it's always give me that error:

> - Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...An unhandled exception occurred: Proxy configuration file
>   C:\Users\nasse\RiderProjects\Solution2\test2\src\proxy-c onfig.json
>   contains parse errors: [1, 1] InvalidSymbol See
>   "C:\Users\nasse\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-T9wrQt\angular-errors.log" for
>   further details.

Comment: ok but how to do that ?

Answer (score 6):

Just had the same error, when updating to angular 14. Change the encoding of the proxy.config.json file from UTF-8-BOM to UTF-8 worked for me.

Comment: My bad was unsaved proxy config :)

Comment: Worked for me as well. Would have never guessed.